# difference between $(this).index() and element.index(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to get the index of input box using `$(this).index()` and was getting wrong index.

After finding in Google applied  `$("input").index(this)` and it worked. So curious to know what is the difference in these two methods and why the earlier one has not worked.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).index()` will return the index with respect to the parent element.

`$("input").index(this)`  returns the index of the passes item based on the set of elements on which .index() was called.

consider this HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then the code,

```
$("input").click(function() {
  alert($(this).index());
  alert($("input").index(this));
});
```

- `alert($(this).index());` will always alert 0, because its the one
  and only child element of its parent TD.
- `alert($("input").index(this));` will return 0 for the first input and 1 for the next input.

Check this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5508/)

Comment: For more info, look at the section under "Return Values" here: https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Nice one @anoopjoshi. I liked it.